# Liferay : unable to read full value from cookies in Controller

Tags: cookies, liferay, liferay-7

I want read value from cookie using Java code.

Example:
I have store value in cookie . like email=abc@xyz.com
When I am trying to fetch **email** value from cookie using below code I am only get "abc". But I want full value "abc@xyz.com"

I am using below code

```
Cookie[] cookies = renderRequest.getCookies();
    for (int i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
        Cookie cookie = cookies[i];
        System.out.print("Name : " + cookie.getName( ) + ",  ");
        System.out.println("Value: " + cookie.getValue( ));
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if the RenderRequest gives you the same cookies as the HttpServletRequest: After all, it's a portlet-request. If you have set the value yourself, and you're not getting the same value back, you probably made a mistake encoding the value when you set it.

Also, as you're obviously in a render request handler, that might be the request of someone who is logged in anyway, and there's no need to set a specific cookie: You can just get the value for the currently signed in user (unless you're looking for somebody else's mail address - however that gets stored in the cookie)

Comment: Cookie is already stored in RenderRequest. because when I get value that only get "abc". Value comming from cookies but some how it's only splits "@" character.

Comment: well, someone did set the cookie - most likely your portlet itself (e.g. you), because otherwise it wouldn't be there. Check how you set the cookie, and especially the encoding. I'm not sure if `@` is a special character that needs encoding for cookies... or how you set it at all...